# looping through 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 ... with modulus c sharp

Tags: c#

I am Trying to create a function for a game
so when I increase a variable n ,  Pressing a button, I do n=(n%4)+1 and successfully I get the sequence 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4. So that way it works, but when I go down in the sequence, starting from one I cant find a formula that would get me the sequence 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1...
any ideas? thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that instead of trying to use modulus to do this, you just do this instead:

```
n = n>1 ? n-1 : 4;
```

Comment: Do I type that as a code? I didn't know the    ?   Operation,  thank you,,  I'll check it out

Comment: it  works thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As well as the solution from Matthew Watson, you can use Unity's `Mathf.Repeat()` [function](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Repeat.html) which is designed to do exactly what you are trying to achieve.

just pass it `n` as the first parameter and the length (4 in this case) as the second.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that function,  let me give it a go,  I'm trying to avoid zero though

Comment: just add one to it and put the length as three and this will avoid 0.

Comment: im trying it but it would give me 0 1 0 1...

Comment: someone else told me a great solution  n=4-(5-n)%4